# Getting error "The script completed but did not return anything."

Tags: google-apps-script

[Actual web page image that should come](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PszqH.png) I am getting error:

> "The script completed but did not return anything."

I have published new version of code but still getting the error after saving the code and error which is coming is "The script completed but did not return anything."

Code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  var op = e.parameter.action;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("some url");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  if (op == "insert")
    return insert_value(e, sheet);

  //Make sure you are sending proper parameters 
  if (op == "read")
    return read_value(e, ss);

  if (op == "update")
    return update_value(e, sheet);

  if (op == "delete")
    return delete_value(e, sheet);
}

//Recieve parameter and pass it to function to handle
function insert_value(request, sheet) {
  var id = request.parameter.id;
  var country = request.parameter.name;

  var flag = 1;
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 1; i <= lr; i++) {
    var id1 = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    if (id1 == id) {
      flag = 0;
      var result = "Id already exist..";
    }
  }

  //add new row with recieved parameter from client
  if (flag == 1) {
    var d = new Date();
    var currentTime = d.toLocaleString();
    var rowData = sheet.appendRow([currentTime, id, country]);  
    var result="Insertion successful";
  }
  result = JSON.stringify({
    "result": result
  });  

  return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(request.parameter.callback + "(" + result + ")")
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);   
  }

function read_value(request, ss) {
  var output  = ContentService.createTextOutput(),
      data = {};
  //Note : here sheet is sheet name , don't get confuse with other operation 
  var sheet = "sheet1";

  data.records = readData_(ss, sheet);

  var callback = request.parameters.callback;
  if (callback === undefined) {
    output.setContent(JSON.stringify(data));
  } else {
    output.setContent(callback + "(" + JSON.stringify(data) + ")");
  }
  output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
  return output;
}


function readData_(ss, sheetname, properties) {
  if (typeof properties == "undefined") {
    properties = getHeaderRow_(ss, sheetname);
    properties = properties.map(function(p) { return p.replace(/\s+/g, '_'); });
  }

  var rows = getDataRows_(ss, sheetname),
      data = [];
  for (var r = 0, l = rows.length; r < l; r++) {
    var row = rows[r],
        record = {};

    for (var p in properties) {
      record[properties[p]] = row[p];
    }
    data.push(record);
  }
  return data;
}

function getDataRows_(ss, sheetname) {
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  return sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
}


function getHeaderRow_(ss, sheetname) {
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  return sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];  
} 


//update function
function update_value(request, sheet) {
  var output  = ContentService.createTextOutput();
  var id = request.parameter.id;
  var flag = 0;
  var country = request.parameter.name;
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 1; i <= lr; i++) {
    var rid = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    if (rid == id) {
      sheet.getRange(i, 3).setValue(country);
      var result = "value updated successfully";
      flag = 1;
    }
  }
  if (flag == 0)
    var result="id not found";
  result = JSON.stringify({
    "result": result
  });  

  return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(request.parameter.callback + "(" + result + ")")
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}

function delete_value(request,sheet) {
  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
  var id = request.parameter.id;
  var country = request.parameter.name;
  var flag = 0;

  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 1; i <= lr; i++) {
    var rid = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    if (rid == id) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
      var result = "value deleted successfully";
      flag = 1;
    }
  }

  if(flag==0)
    var result="id not found";
  result = JSON.stringify({
    "result": result
  });  

  return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(request.parameter.callback + "(" + result + ")")
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

HTML script section

```
<script>
  var script_url = "apps script webapp url";

  // Make an AJAX call to Google Script
  function insert_value() {
    $("#re").css("visibility","hidden");
    document.getElementById("loader").style.visibility = "visible";
    $('#mySpinner').addClass('spinner');

    var id1 = $("#id").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var url = script_url + "?callback=ctrlq&name=" + name + "&id=" + id1 + "&action=insert";
    var request = jQuery.ajax({
      crossDomain: true,
      url: url ,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    });
  }

  function update_value(){
    $("#re").css("visibility","hidden");
    document.getElementById("loader").style.visibility = "visible";

    var id1 = $("#id").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var url = script_url + "?callback=ctrlq&name=" + name + "&id=" + id1 + "&action=update";
    var request = jQuery.ajax({
      crossDomain: true,
      url: url ,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    });
  }

  function delete_value(){
    $("#re").css("visibility","hidden");
    document.getElementById("loader").style.visibility = "visible";
    $('#mySpinner').addClass('spinner');

    var id1 = $("#id").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var url = script_url + "?callback=ctrlq&name=" + name + "&id=" + id1 + "&action=delete";
    var request = jQuery.ajax({
      crossDomain: true,
      url: url ,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    });
  }


  // print the returned data
  function ctrlq(e) {
    $("#re").html(e.result);
    $("#re").css("visibility","visible");
    read_value();
  }

  function read_value() {
    // Other code here to process the result
  }

</script>
```

HTML function calls:

```
<body>
<div align="center">
<h1>Operations .</h1> 
<p>This is simple application<p>

<form >
ID
<input type = "text" name ="id" id="id">
Name
<input type = "text" name ="name" id="name">

</form>

<div id="loader"></div>

<p id="re"></p>

<input type = "button"  id = "b1" onClick="insert_value()" value = "Insert"></input>
<input type="button" onclick="read_value()" value="Read" />
<input type="button" onclick="update_value()" value="Update" />
<input type="button" onclick="delete_value()" value="Delete" />
<div id="showData"></div>
</div>
</body>
<div align="center">
</div>
<html>
```

It should show web page for performing operation shown in screenshot
web page:

[image]

Comment: I improved formatting but you must change the link to your image.

Answer (score 4):

The error is correct - consider what happens when no parameters are given to your webapp function `doGet`. This scenario occurs when the webapp is visited via browser.  To resolve this error, you must return something:

```
function doGet(e) {
  console.log({event: e});
  ...
  if (op)
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Unsupported operation");
  else
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(...);
  }
}
```

The default response will vary based on how your webapp is used - if you intend to use the webapp only as a crud backend vs. if you plan to have it host the web interface as well.

If the webapp is to host the interface as well, your HTML should use the built in client-server communication (`google.script.run...`) rather than `jQuery.ajax`. Review the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) in detail. This pattern will allow you to report and even handle errors in your server code execution.

Comment: @ tehhowch Thanks for the response now my web page is coming but after entering details it is not coming in spreadsheet.Please refer screenshot below