# Script completed but didn't display anything

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336082/how-to-solve-common-errors-in-google-apps-script-development) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53910428/getting-error-the-script-completed-but-did-not-return-anything) but did not find an answer to my issue.
I've the below code, that is receiving JSON data from the form, and insert data at the SpreedSheet,  :

```
function doPost(e) {
  // Prevent concurrent access overwritting data
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  // As we are passing JSON in the body, we need to unpairse it
  var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  e.parameter = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  
  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
  //  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FILE_Id);
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    
    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

Execution is done perfectly in terms of adding data to the sheet, but I've issue in the `return`, as I got the below string:

```sh
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>خطأ</title><style type="text/css">body {background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}.errorMessage {font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 25px;}</style></head><body style="margin:20px"><div><img alt="Google Apps Script" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/logo.png"></div><div style="text-align:center;font-family:monospace;margin:50px auto 0;max-width:600px">اكتمل النص البرمجي إلا أنه لم يعرض شيئًا.</div></body></html>
```

The translation of the Arabic text is: `Script completed but didn't display anything`

**UPDATE**

I modified my code to use single return statement as below, but still getting the same message:

```
function handleResponse(e) {
  var result, message;
  // Prevent concurrent access overwritting data
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(1000);  // 3000 wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  // As we are passing JSON in the body, we need to unpairse it
  var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  e.parameter = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  
  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
  //  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FILE_Id);
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(DATA_SHEET);
    //var report = doc.getSheetByName(REPORT_SHEET);
    
    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    // var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    var nextRow = lastRow + 1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    if(lastRow < 10){
      RefID = "PRF.00" + lastRow
    } else {
      if(lastRow < 100){
        RefID = "PRF.0" + lastRow
      } else {
        RefID = "PRF." + lastRow
      }
    }
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Ref"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column

        row.push(RefID);
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
         row.push(new Date());
        } else { // else use header name to get data
          row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
       }
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    /*********************************************/

    var link = printPDF(RefID)
    console.log("PDF created")

    /*********************************************/
    // return json success results
    result = "success";
    message = link;
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    result = "error";
    message = e;
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
  return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":result, "message": message}))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Comment: @MetricRat That is wrong as  `sheet.getLastRow()+1` returns a number

Comment: Hasan: I suggest you to add some console.log statements if order to confirm where exactly is your `doPost` function ending.

Add one before each `return` and one more before the last `}`. If you need further help please add enough details in order to be able to reproduce your tests.

Comment: For example, when you redeploy your Web Apps as new version, the result will be changed?

Comment: @Rubén I added console.log but nothing shown up, the script is running as web app.

Comment: @Tanaike it is running as web app, console.log did not work with me

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I had commented for the result of `Script completed but didn't display anything`. I apologize for this. But I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: About your replying of `it is running as web app, console.log did not work with me`, in this case, in order to see the log using `console.log` when the Web Apps is accessed, there are 2 methods. 1. From your question, although I cannot understand about the client side, when your client side doesn't use the access token, the log by `console.log` cannot be saved. If you want to check the log using `console.log`, please add the access token for the request header in the client side. By this, you can see the log.

Comment: 2. As another method, when you cannot use the access token for the client side, you can see the log when the Google Apps Script project is linked to the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project. I summarized about this at [my repository](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#checklog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error to be as below:
the `doPost(e)` is calling `handleResponse(e)` the system expect the return to be from the `doPost(e)` itself.

I made a mistake in my question in real, first in the snippets in my question (for code simplicity) I mentioned the call is done from the `doPost(e)` which looks to be mislead the friends who read my question.

Now my working code is:

```
function doPost(e){
  output = handleResponse(e)
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(output)
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON); 
}

function handleResponse(e) {
  var result, message;
  // Prevent concurrent access overwritting data
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(1000);  // 3000 wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  // As we are passing JSON in the body, we need to unpairse it
  var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  e.parameter = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  
  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
  //  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FILE_Id);
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(DATA_SHEET);
    //var report = doc.getSheetByName(REPORT_SHEET);
    
    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    // var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    var nextRow = lastRow + 1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    if(lastRow < 10){
      RefID = "PRF.00" + lastRow
    } else {
      if(lastRow < 100){
        RefID = "PRF.0" + lastRow
      } else {
        RefID = "PRF." + lastRow
      }
    }
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Ref"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column

        row.push(RefID);
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
         row.push(new Date());
        } else { // else use header name to get data
          row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
       }
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    /*********************************************/

    var link = printPDF(RefID)
    console.log("PDF created")

    /*********************************************/
    // return json success results
    result = "success";
    message = link;
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    result = "error";
    message = e;
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
    var output = JSON.stringify({"result":result, "message": message});
  }
  return output;
}
```