# How can I intercept data being sent to a Googlesheet from Javascript programatically/implicitly?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I am making a [map painter programme](https://matthewkeracher.github.io/Excel_DM.js/), that takes in X, Y and colour data from user input and stores in a [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lGlBfPSeCIjMOCyAUvtOiaUDU0f1J_l5FV_N0sRUY48/edit?usp=sharing).

The data is sent to the spreadsheet as a form, following this [solution](https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets). This solution works if the user is filling out the 'form' and hitting the 'submit' button. I have the following `EventListener` to listen and intercept:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
      
    e.preventDefault();
   

    const newData = new FormData(form);
    const mapData = e.target.action

    console.log('+++++++++INTERCEPTING++++++++++')
       

  fetch(mapData, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: newData,
    
  })
  

LoadMap()

})
```

However, when the user is simply painting I want a way to send the X, Y and colour data to the spreadsheet without the need for the user to hit submit. For this, I have the following `function`:

```
 function paint() {

            var paintColour = document.getElementById("paintFill").value
           

            gridCTX.fillStyle = paintColour;
                 
            //PAINTS THE SQUARE
            console.log('')
            console.log('+++++++++PAINTING DATA++++++++++')
            console.log('Painting ' + gridCTX.fillStyle  + ' at ' + rx + ',' + ry)
            gridCTX.fillRect(rx * tileSize, ry * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize)
            paintArray.push({x:rx, y: ry, z: rz, fill: paintColour})
            console.table(paintArray)

           
            //AUTOMATICALLY FILL EDITOR AS PAINTING
            
            
            document.getElementById('testFill').value = paintColour
                
            //AUTOMAGICALLY SUBMIT FORM DATA
            document.forms['mapData'].submit();
            
              
            //NEED TO PREVENT DEFAULT
                      

          }
```

When `paint()` is called and `document.forms['mapData'].submit()` I know that the `EventListener` is not triggering on "submit," and therefore refers to clicking the button rather than the form being sumbitted programmatically.

So, I am not sure how to proceed with my programme. I have some ideas... is there some other event other than 'submit' that can handle the programmatic form submission? Or perhaps there is a way I could put the `fetch` etc. that is contained within the `EventListener` `function(e)` into the `paint()` function.

I want to avoid the user being redirected to this screen:

[image: Google appscript page]

I realise Post and Get are not 'secure' but the data is not sensitive. I am a beginner with Javascript, so any help in resolving this issue would be much appreciated.

This is *not* the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410063/how-can-i-listen-to-the-form-submit-event-in-javascript/70980807#70980807) which asks how to listen to the submit button being clicked on a form. I want to 'listen' or act contingently upon the `document.forms['mapData'].submit()` line.

Comment: Are you using a `doGet` function? This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53910428/getting-error-the-script-completed-but-did-not-return-anything) may give you an idea of what could be happening

Comment: I have a `doGet()` in my sheets appScript. The script is completing and everything is fine; my issue is that I cannot intercept the programmatic submission of the form and stop being redirected to this screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.forms['mapData'].dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));`

I got the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916298/why-wont-form-submit-trigger-the-submit-event).